# My reputation just disappeared from the top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, mobile-web

[image: mobile screenshot]

At some point in the last hour, as the screen capture shows, my reputation number vanished in the top status bar. This is being reported from my Samsung Android phone on a mobile Chrome browser. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Bit of a click-bait title, yeah? Your reputation didn't disappear (like you're at 1 rep or something), just the appearance of your rep number and badges. It's likely an A/B test to see if removing it on mobile makes sense.

Comment: At least we found the mysterious up voter of sql questions ... ;)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I suspected A/B testing, but still wanted to ask in case this might be a permanent change.

Comment: It's also being questioned over at meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309242/why-are-rep-and-badges-now-collapsed-on-safari-ipad - My screen is plenty big enough for the Ego, I mean Rep, numbers. It's not like the additional space has permitted a larger Avatar; it's more of a loss than a gain.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is one of the ch-ch-ch-changes mentioned in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/323179). It's responsive design, as you can see in this gif:

[image: marquee]

Comment: Yeah, it is responsive in that it responds to different widths. Does it display properly on different screen sizes though? No. No it does not.

Comment: Back in the day, we had `<marquee>`, now it's called responsive.

Comment: Yeah but it's a *bad* change to a *poor* response considering what isn't reduced instead.

Comment: The threshold seems to be at 980 px.

Comment: The search bar should definitely be shrunken before the rep and badges are hidden...